# Cassandra read performance comparison with OS file read

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is there a possibility of using Cassandra as a temporary storage to store results of an RDBMS query and later do a lazy read from Cassandra when required? If I use it so, can I get any performance improvement while reading  when compared to reading data on disk file?

Comment: What makes you think it would be more efficient than using that RDBMS in the first place to store cached data, and then read from its cache?

Comment: RDBMS cache may not store the entire data. I was thinking to leverage the write speed of Cassandra. Then I thought whether will writes be faster than an 'mmap'ed file to which the RDBMS writes. So the question.

Comment: If anything, you will manage to make everything slower. Also, there's insufficient information to answer this question properly. Cassandra can't read a file faster than OS, nor can it write to a file faster than OS.